# Environment variable for a user's Documents folder?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

When I'm developing with Xcode or maybe using tools like gulp or grunt I notice that the tools try to access resources from an incorrect path. I've observed the problem in more that one program so clearly these programs are using some kind of environment path or shared configuration to attempt to discover the full path to the project folder. The path these programs try to use is both consistent and always wrong.

For example:

```
Looking for JS files in /Users/username/Documents/Documents/AwesomeProject*
```

The repeated `Documents` folder in the above path is incorrect.

What environment variable might these programs be using to divine this path?

Comment: You mean `$HOME`?

Comment: Hi, echo $HOME returns: /Users/username/Documents so that is not the case.

Comment: On my system `$HOME` returns `/Users/username` and not  `/Users/username/Documents`, so it is likely your $HOME variable is set wrong. Check the following files: `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, you might have an error in your environment variables.

Comment: Have you examined the Gruntfile.js?  It should be listed in there.